# Gradle doesn't include transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle, transitive-dependency, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to use [spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc) for testing a controller in my little application. Since I use gradle as build tool I added the dependency to it like this:

```
testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:1.0.0.M1'
```

It succeeds to retrieve spring-test-mvc, and compile the tests. But executing the tests fails, because it doesn't seem to include transient dependencies like mvc test.

Among others it complains about not finding

```
org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest
```

Which is part of the spring-test.jar, which is included as a dependency in spring-test-mvc s pom.xml https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/pom.xml

I can fix that problem by including the dependency explicitely in the build file:

```
testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.1.RELEASE'
```

But it just gets replaced by the next problem. I tried to explicitly ask for transient dependencies:

```
testCompile ('org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:1.0.0.M1') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

But that doesn't seedm to change anything.

So the question is: How do I get gradle to include transitive dependencies in the classpath.

Note: Transitive dependencies seem to work fine outside of tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the POM. http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/org/springframework/spring-test-mvc/1.0.0.M1/spring-test-mvc-1.0.0.M1.pom does not declare any dependencies.

Comment: Hmm that would explain it. Lets see what the developers of the project say: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/issues/41